# Ambiguity between std::size_t and Fpdfview::size_t

Tags: excel, pdf, c++builder

I have two components, in `Excel_2K_SRVR.h` and `PDFium.hpp`, that are being used in file `Unit1.h`.

The program fails to compile and throws an error from `utilcls.h`, where the content cannot be changed. The error is in `class TPtrBase` in the `private` section `void* operator new (size_t);` like:

> Ambiguity between std::size_t and Fpdfview::size_t

Does that mean that I will not be able to use both Excel and PDFium components in the same program?

`Unit1.cpp` looks like this:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma link "PDFium"
#pragma link "Excel_2K_SRVR"
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
```

Comment: How does PDFium define `size_t`? Is there any `#ifdef` you could use to tell it `size_t` already exists?

Comment: PDFium looks like only in my edited post

Comment: "*Does that mean that I will not be able to use both Excel and PDFium components in the same program?*" - no. It just means you can't use them in the same unit together.  Separate them into different units that don't see each other, and then you should be fine.

Comment: Yes, but how to connect new Unit2 with Unit1 without #include